# why electrostatic force is called force

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics

My title looks bit silly but I will explain my question .

Why have the nucleus of atom and why have electrons circulating outside of nucleus force the cause electrons to stay in proximity to nucleus in called
 electric force or electrostatic force ...but as far as I know force always accelerate mass so i am bit confused about statement force here ok electron are attracted to protons but they do not accelerate they just stay within proximity

Comment: Please, consider re-writing your question with correct grammar. It's been hard for me to understand what your question was.

Answer (score 1):

It CAUSES acceleration! When a body is in a circular path an acceleration called centripetal acceleration ($a_{cp}$) has effect on it. Imagine that you are in a car moving relatively fast and the car sarts to move in circles.You will feel that you are pushed towards the side of the car. That centripetal force acts on the car too but because of the fricion of the car's tires it can continue it~s circular path. The exact same thing happens with the electron around a nucleus, or a sattelite orbiting the Earth. They are on a circular orbit where the centripetal force is equal to the electrostatic or the gravitational force. The centripetal force is: 
$$F_{cp}=m\frac{v^{2}}{r}$$
Then the centripetal acceleration is
$$a_{cp}=\frac{v^{2}}{r}.$$
So the electron is in an orbit with radius
$$r=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q_{nucleus}Q_{electron}}{mv^{2}}.$$
Remember, when something is in a circular orbit it ALWAYS has acceleration. Furter reading : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#Uniform_circular_motion .
Now I have to crush your expectations because the electron is not in circular orbit. It's a wave and it's "motion" is described by the Time Independent Schrödinger Equation (TISE)
I hope my answer was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Historical background in short**

From classical electromagnetic point of view, an electron orbiting around the nucleus accelerates and therefore radiates EM wave.  As a result, the electron loses its energy and will spiral inwards.

J.J. Thomson proposed the plum-pudding model and abandoned the planetary model.  However, Rutherford gold-foil scattering experiment disproved the plum-pudding model and proposed there should be an intensive positively charged nucleus in an atom.

[**Bohr model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) of atom was introduced.  The electron is only allowed in particular angular momentum and hence its energy.  We say the angular momentum as well as the energy are quantized:

$$mvr=\frac{nh}{2\pi}$$

with this relation we can derive emission/absorption spectral lines for hydrogen atoms:

$$\frac{1}{\lambda}=R\left( \frac{1}{m^2}-\frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$

In the language of modern quantum mechanics, the electron stays in a particular energy state with **stationary wave function**.  That's quite odd from classical point of view, the electron is ***stationary*** but with ***non-zero angular momentum!!***  There're many strange phenomena in quantum regime that is too long to discuss here.

Last but not least, photon is either absorbed or emitted when the electron transiting from one energy level to another.  The wave function for an electron is no longer stationary in this case.

Answer (score -1):

1) The adjective "electrostatic" does **not** mean it doesn't cause acceleration. It is called like that because you don't need moving charges to have that force. A rest charge already creates that force. However, for a magnetic force you need a charge with nonzero velocity. The "static" token refers to the cause, not to the consequence.

2) You can have forces without having acceleration, if there are several forces compensating each other. That's what happens with yourself: you have a weight, but you don't sink in the ground because there is a normal force compensating your weight. Forces cause acceleration, but the fact that there are forces doesn't mean you're accelerated, because they might cancel each other.

Comment: Are the electrons accelerating or not? Do the forces on them cancel out? Which forces cancel out?

Comment: Your question is not concrete enough. What electrons are you talking about? Do you mean in an atom? But what model of atom are you considering? Because Rutherford's model has little to do with the quantum model.  That's why I didn't talk about your concrete example. My answer was general. Electrostatic force is the one created by two charges on each other. As soon as there are 2 charges, there's force between them. It's electrostatic because that force already exists when the charges are at rest. For a more complete Lorentz force you need velocity, but electostatic is there ALWAYS.

Comment: As for the second part, I only said that you can have a force compensated with other forces, so that the body is in equilibrium.

Comment: The question is asking about electrons in atoms. It is probably using the Rutherford Model. ee is asking : if there is a force between the electrons and the nucleus, why aren't the electrons accelerating? They only *stay within proximity.* You do not seem to be answering this question.

Comment: Okay, now it is a concrete question. In the Rutherford model, electrons actually move with acceleration, so yes, they are accelerated because there's a force.  In fact, they describe circular orbits, which have a normal acceleration, and it's caused by that force. The thing is that electrons would lose energy and they will finally fall to the nucleus, because they are attracted to the the nucleus. This was a big problem for this theory, and this was overcome with quantum mechanics.

Comment: So there are 2 different parts. On the one hand, it's called electrostatic because that attraction would also happen if the charges were somehow fixed, unable to move (if there were another force to avoid they go to each other). On the other hand, most electrons don't fall to the nucleus because the atom is actually more complex and you cannot see it as two classical charges, you need quantum mechanics. The atom just works differently.