# Why do accelerating electrons not emit electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, physical-chemistry

I've read at many places that accelerating charged particles emit electromagnetic radiation, but on [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/09._The_Hydrogen_Atom/Bohr%27s_Hydrogen_Atom) article on Bohr's hydrogen atom, at the end part, it's written under *Limitations of the Bohr Model* that:

> The Bohr Model does not account for the fact that accelerating electrons do not emit electromagnetic radiation.

I'm getting confused, can anybody explain this?

Comment: Why do you think the two statements contradict? Electrons *are* charged particles.

Comment: Because electrons are charged particles, so, they must emit EMradiation when accelerated but it is written there that electrons do not emit EM radiation when accelerated, so the two statements contradict.

Comment: You have the "oposite" typo in your question, when quoting the article. As written, your question does not make sense.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using these kinds of online resources for your learning. As you just saw, they’re full of big mistakes — it’s quite possible that nobody has _ever_ checked the book for correctness.

Comment: Please also refer to another post of my [*here*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381959/why-electrostatic-force-is-called-force/382018#382018).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a misfortunate (and possibly ungrammatical) phrasing. Under the headline *Limitations of the Bohr model* the linked article states that.

> The Bohr Model does not account for the fact that accelerating electrons do not emit electromagnetic radiation.

What is meant is that electrons rotating around an atomic nucleus are accelerated, and therefore must radiate and lose their energy. However under the Bohr model they do not emit any radiation. Thus, this is a shortcoming of this model.

Answer (score 3):

The Bohr model was invented so as to explain the [spectrum of light from the Hydrogen atom,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html). By classical theory the spectrum should be a continuous radiation  and the electron should fall on the proton and neutralize it, thus no atoms. With his quantization of angular momentum postulate the model reproduces the spectrum, and the [energy levels seen.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html)

The free electrons when a[ccelerated radiate](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/synchrotron.html).

It is one of the set of data   that necessitated the theory of  quantum mechanics , together with the [black body](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) radiation and the [photoelectric effect.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html)